# Project Rider TFVC Config

Tags: tfs, jetbrains-ide, rider

When setting up Project Rider TFS config I am getting below error.  But path seems to be valid.[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I have tested installing `riderRS-171.4456.199.exe` (Windows), the TFS Integration plugin has been bundled with Rider and enabled VCS-TFVC successfully.

However, the command line tool is not using the  `tf.exe` under VS.

> You must have the [TF command line tool](https://github.com/Microsoft/team-explorer-everywhere/releases) installed to be able to
>   use TFVC features. The minimum version supported by the plugin is
>   14.0.3. To install the tool, download the latest "TEE-CLC-14.*.*.zip" file and extract it to a known location. After extracting the files,
>   you must accept the license agreement. To do so, open a Command
>   Prompt/Terminal window, navigate to the extracted directory, and run
>   `tf eula`. After reading the EULA, enter y `enter code here`to accept
>   it. **NOTE:** If you forget to do this, the plugin may fail to load
>   with a RuntimeException.

For the tool to be detected by the plugin, you must set the location of the executable in the Settings/Preferences menu by following these instructions:

1. Go to RD Settings  Version Control -TFVC
2. In the **Path to tf executable** text field, navigate to the location of
       the tf executable.
3. Click **Test** to test that the executable has been found and is working
   as expected.
4. Click **Apply** then **OK** to save and exit.

Besides, if you intend to use the tf tools from the command line, you may want to **add this folder to your PATH environment variable as well**.

More details please refer this [tutorial](http://java.visualstudio.com/Docs/tools/intelliJ#_tfvc-support).

Comment: Hi I was able to catch hold the tf.cmd file.  But after setting it up I receive "KEY_TF_BAD_EXIT_CODE" while trying to update file.  I assume that is the way we can get latest.